# How to make CakePHP validation more secure?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Recently I finished tutorial about create simple blog using CakePHP - here is link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html
Creating validation form is very easy and fast, but I noticed one issue with that.

File named post.ctp contains:

```
  echo $this->Form->create('Post');
  echo $this->Form->input('title');
```

And it generates form to end user with this input:

```
<input id="PostTitle" type="text" required="required" maxlength="50" name="data[Post][title]">
```

Someone who is using Firefox Firebug can change the html code before submit form from: `name="data[Post][title]"` to: `name="data[Post][author]"`. The result of this will update column named "author", not "title", and also allowing to update database with empty data for "title".

In the folder named "Model" validation rule in Post.php doesn't prevents that:

```
class Post extends AppModel {

public $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    )
);

}
```

How to secure my application and not allow someone to update other columns in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cake's [security component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) includes [form tampering](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#form-tampering-prevention) protection. You will need to add the security component in your controller(s):

```
public $components = array('Security');
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfect. I just updated line in my components to `public $components = array('Session', 'Security');` and nothing more to configure. It works at start. When I tried to do the same I got message "The request has been black-holed". Perfect. They should include that in first tutorial, because it's important.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Model documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model).  There are at least two ways to handle this.

1. You can pass `fieldlist` as the third parameter when calling `save()`.
2. You can set the Model's `whitelist` property before calling `save()`.

I haven't used this yet but the [Security Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent) is another option.

Comment: Definitely use Security Component. Read the linked manual page for more info.